# Complete DataFrame with missing steps python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame which misses some rows. It actually has the following format:

```
id step var1 var2
1  1    a    h
2  1    b    i
3  1    c    g
1  3    d    k
2  2    e    l
5  2    f    m
6  1    g    n
...
```

An observation should pass through every steps. I mean id ==1 has step 1 and 3 but misses step 2 (which I don't want). id==2 has step 1 and 2 and there is no step 3 and this is fine because there is no gap. id ==5 has step 2 but doesn't have step 1 so I am missing a line there.
I need to add some rows to complete the steps, I would keep var1 var2 and id as the same.

I would like to obtain this df :

```
id step var1 var2
1  1    a    h
2  1    b    i
3  1    c    g
1  3    d    k
2  2    e    l
5  2    f    m
6  1    g    n
1  2    a    h
5  1    f    m
...
```

It would be awesome if anyone could help with a smooth solution

Comment: Kindly add the complete expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can try pivot the table then `ffill` and `bfill`:

```
(df.pivot(index='id', columns='step')
   .groupby(level=0, axis=1)
   .apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
   .stack()
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
    id  step var1 var2
0    1     1    a    h
1    1     2    e    l
2    1     3    d    k
3    2     1    b    i
4    2     2    e    l
5    2     3    d    k
6    3     1    c    g
7    3     2    e    l
8    3     3    d    k
9    5     1    c    g
10   5     2    f    m
11   5     3    d    k
12   6     1    g    n
13   6     2    f    m
14   6     3    d    k
```